# how to select entity with relationship to other entity in EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

How can I get the list of products for specific project without including project? Something similar to

```
select p.Id, p.Name 
from product p
inner join ProjectProduct j on p.Id = j.ProductId and j.ProjectId = @Id
```

The closest solution that I have is

```
var products = await (from proj in context.Project select proj)
                    .Where(proj => proj.Id == 1)
                    .Select(proj => proj.Product)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

but this returns a `List<List<Product>>`
in addition I need to be able to add the order by and pagination to that
I know that I can do it by raw sql like this

```
var param1 = new SqlParameter("@Id", id);
var query = @"select * from product p
inner join ProjectProduct j
on p.Id = j.ProductId and j.ProjectId = @Id ";

var queryable = context.product.FromSqlRaw(query, param1).AsQueryable();
await HttpContext.AddPaginationToHeader(queryable);

var products = await queryable.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Paginate(paginationDTO).ToListAsync();
```

But I was hoping to do it by linq to entity

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Project> Project { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectProduct
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Harald Coppoolse's response on another post
and for those that have the same problem

here are the steps
1- we define our query as queryable

```
var queryable = context.Project
                .Where(proj => proj.Id == id)
                .SelectMany(p => p.Product).AsQueryable();
```

2- Now we can pass the query to SQL server like this

```
var products = await queryable.OrderBy(x => 
x.Name).Skip(...).Take(...).ToListAsync();
```

for Skip and Take we can create a generic Extension for IQueryable
and add a method to that with return of

```
return queryable
                .Skip((paginationDTO.Page - 1) * paginationDTO.PageSize)
                .Take(paginationDTO.PageSize);
```

and of course our paginationDTO is nothing more than a POCO class with 2 properties of page and pageSize

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var products = await  context.Project
                      .Where(proj => proj.Id == 1)
                      .Select( proj=>proj.Products)
                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

if you want to order product after this you can do this common way

```
products= products.OrderBy(p=>p.Name).ToList();
```

it can be put in one line but EF sometimes generates a very ridiculous  Sql script, so better to do this separately.

Comment: Hi Serge Thanks for your reply that solved the problem of list<list<product>> but how can I apply the OrderBy for product

Comment: The way you are doing OrderBy is happening in memory which is not the way I need , is ther a way to add the orderby in the query?

Comment: It doesn't matter where do you order them, in SQL server memory or Web Server memory since you will be downloading  the same records, only in a different order. IMHO it will be faster if you order them after dowloading.